# how to use liipimaginebundle filterset in twig

Tags: liipimaginebundle

I have following filterset in my config file and my problem is using different filter in twig

```
liip_imagine:
filter_sets:
    my_thumb:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
            relative_resize: { scale: 0.5 }   # Transforms 50x40 to 125x100
            relative_resize: { scale: 1.5 }   # Transforms 50x40 to 125x100
            crop: { start: [10, 20], size: [120, 90] }
```

if there was one filter it would be like this,

```
<img src="{{ asset(['images/', news.picPath]|join| imagine_filter('my_thumb'))  }}" alt="{{ news.title }} image not found" class="large" />
```

but now i do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In this config you hane only one filter set named my_thumb. If you want more filters you should separate them in your config like this:

```
iip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
                filters:
                    thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
        my_half_scale_resizer:
            quality: 80
                filters:
                    relative_resize: { scale: 0.5 }   # Transforms 50x40 to 125x100
        my_cropped_image:
            quality: 70
                filters:
                    crop: { start: [10, 20], size: [120, 90] }
```

And then in your twig file you can use:

```
<img src="{{ asset(imagepath| imagine_filter('thumb_50x50')) }}">
<img src="{{ asset(imagepath| imagine_filter('my_half_scale_resizer')) }}">
<img src="{{ asset(imagepath| imagine_filter('my_cropped_image')) }}">
```